# Implement a tokeniser in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to implement a tokeniser in python (without using NLTK libraries) that splits a string into words using blank spaces. Example usage is:

```
>> tokens = tokenise1(“A (small, simple) example”)
>> tokens
[‘A’, ‘(small,’, ‘simple)’, ‘example’]
```

I can get some of the way using regular expressions but my return value includes white spaces which I don't want. How do i get the correct return value as per example usage?

What i have so far is:

```
def tokenise1(string):
    return re.split(r'(\S+)', string)
```

and it returns:

```
['', 'A', ' ', '(small,', ' ', 'simple)', ' ', 'example', '']
```

so i need to get rid of the white space in the return

Comment: string.split() is enough for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output is having spaces because you capture them using `()`. Instead you can split like

```
re.split(r'\s+', string)
['A', '(small,', 'simple)', 'example']
```

- `\s+` Matches one or more spaces.